# ValueError: could not convert string to float -on_text in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need help pls. I'm making an app and I have a TextInput where I assigned a funcion in on_text. The function do a procces. It's turn the string of the TextInput to float and after this multiply this value times 0.10 and after that, it's turn back this value in String for being showed up in a Label.. this is working, when writing in the textinput automatically change the value in my label and that's great, the problem is when deleting the last number and the TextInput is in blanked. I got this next Error

tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

main.py

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    #Variables Shopping Cart
    var1= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart.png")
    var2= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart2.png")
    

    #Functions Items
    def list_items(self):
        tornillo= self.ids.input_tornillo.text
        tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1
        tornillo2= str(tornillo1)
        self.ids.label_tornillo.text= tornillo2

        if '' in tornillo:
              tornillo = 0
```

```
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                multiline: True
                on_text: root.list_items()
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                

            Label:
                id: label_tornillo
                text: ""
                #text: root.ids.input_tornillo.text*2
```

Comment: Try changing `tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1` with `tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1 if tornillo else ""`.

Comment: You are repeating "tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1"  two times..

Comment: Look carefully.

Comment: OMG!!! U are right! I  didn't know u can put an "if" inside a variable! IT works! Thank U very much!! I need to learn more of this.. I don't know how to work this at all,

Comment: can U explain me what this part is doing - if tornillo else ""?

Comment: It's like `if len(tornillo) > 0: tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.1; else: tornillo1= ""`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. then this would be a kind of shorcut of Python to determine something between an if and else.

Comment: By the way the code I had to modified it a bit.. I needed to put the str too. in the same variable. because It was not working just like U said me.. but ur answer helped me so much, The final code was this:    tornillo1= str(round(float(tornillo) * 0.1,2)) if tornillo else "0.0"